# Shorting a Synthetic Long

Tags: option-pricing, synthetic

I have the following information:

```
Call Premium: 0.30
Put Premium: 40.4
Strike: 130
1-Month Risk-Free Rate: 0%
Market Price: $85.00
```

If I use the Synthetic Long formula I get a price of: `$89.90`

```
Synthetic-Long = call - put + X/(1+Rf)^t
Synthetic-Long = 0.30 - 40.4 + 130/[(1+0.00)^(30/360)]
Synthetic-Long = $89.90
```

This is significantly higher than the market price. If the Investor buys the stock at the market price `$85.00` how many options and bonds must they buy/sell?

Shorting the Synthetic would make the formula:

```
-(Synthetic-Long) = -call + put - X/(1+Rf)^t
```

Since 1 option contract = 100 shares,

then sell 1 call & buy 1 put, but how much of the bond must they sell? (assuming US treasury, & assuming the Risk-Free Rate  is 0%)